# How to edit CSS in Luma theme in Magento 2.1?

Tags: css, magento-2.1, magento2.1.0, luma-theme

I am trying to change css of `Magento 2.1` Luma theme but its not working.

What will be the better way to modify css in `Magento 2.1` Luma theme ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go through previous answer steps and go to and edit module wise css given path below

```
project/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/module_name/web/css/source
```

and edit common style given path below

```
project/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/web/css/source
```

Answer (score 2):

Login in admin => Stores => Configuration => Advance => Developer

In Front-end development workflow section 
Select Workflow type => Client Side Less Compilation
and save config after that clean cache and then edit and check your changes.

You can also use grunt for less compilation check below links.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Answer (score 0):

First you have to configure compilation of style in admin path given below

```
Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Front-end development workflow
```

change to

```
Client side less compilation
```

- Clear cache

Then edit your theme styles module wise and other web/css/source (common style)

Comment: Hello Dipesh, thanks for your answer. can you please share the answer step by step with specified file path? Thanks